# Getting page not found on custom module Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm building a Magento 2 module, I need to set up a frontpage page and show some information, I have created my routing:

routes.xml (in `namespace/modulename/etc/frontend`)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
  <router id="standard">
    <route id="namespace_modulename" frontName="modulename">
        <module name="Namespace_ModuleName"/>
    </route>
 </router>
</config>
```

I have also my Controller:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Controller\Index;


use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * Index constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }



    /**
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Test";
        exit;
    }

}
```

When i go to `modulename/index/index` I'm getting g page not found.

Not sure why, any ideas? Already done magento upgrade and i can see the module there.

My module registration:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
//Your content ok
```

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Modulename" schema_version="1.0.1" setup_version="1.0.1"/>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your controller is located inside

> namespace/modulename/Controller/Index

and create a module.xml file.

Comment: Already done, still cant get the hello world from the execute function on my browser, im getting page not found, already done re index also.

Comment: Did you create module.xml file inside 'namespace/modulename/etc/' ? It should work.

Comment: Yes its working now, changed to lower case the letters.

Comment: @lucasvm1980, have you fixed this issue ?

Comment: Yes, using lowecase on module name.